# Show only one element and hide others without toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been researching this and many of the answers involve toggle function. The problem is I want one elements to be shown at all time, which isn't possible if toggle is used (they may accidently click something and it disappears). So I was doing it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#goals").hide();
    $("#History").addClass("selected");

    $("#History").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#history").show();
        $("#goals").hide();
        $("#History").addClass("selected");
        $("#Goals").removeClass("selected");

    });
    $("#Goals").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#goals").show();
        $("#history").hide();
        $("#Goals").addClass("selected");
        $("#History").removeClass("selected");
    });
});
```

Except it's prob too tedious and I'm sure there's a better way. I'm trying to find solutions that use hide and show only or if the requirement can be fulfilled. Any help is appreciated...I'm not advanced at jQuery yet so please provide explanation. Thank you

Comment: if you want something to be shown all the time, then just use css and add !important to make sure it is always shown

Comment: Do you really use the ID `History` and the ID `history`, and `Goals` and `goals`??

Comment: @Huangism Using '!important' is a bad idea. It shows a bad programming style.

Comment: @reporter well in this case I don't see what harm it could do.

Comment: @Huangism it will almost always do harm - you really should never use it except as a last resort, and there are many possible answers to this question so the last resort is not required.

Comment: @Archer yes many possible answers which is why I left a comment, I believe as long as you know what you are doing using important is not a bad idea. I rather save the js logic and use css in certain situations

Comment: @Huangism I think you should just accept that it was bad advice and leave it at that.

Comment: @archer to each their own

Comment: The diff ID is because one is for the link(goal) and the other is for the div that contains the hidden text(Goal). Same for history.

@Huangism it's not shown at all time...I meant showing one element at a time, but not giving user the ability to hide/close it. Which is why I asked a solution without toggle

Answer (score 2):

You can give them a class.. or just combine the them in one selector

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#goals").hide();
    $("#History").addClass("selected");
    var eles = $("#History,#Goals");
    eles.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).show().addClass('selected'); // show and add class to current clicked
        eles.not(this).hide().removeClass('selected');  // hide and remove class for the other one
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**  I didn't notice you actually had different id's

```
var hg = $("#history,#goals");
var HG = $("#History,#Goals");
HG.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $('#'+this.id.toLowerCase());
    el.show();
    hg.not(el).hide();
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    HG.not(this).removeClass("selected");    
});
```

Comment: Beat me to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, how exactly does 'var HG = $("#History,#Goals");' work? I've only seen 1 single ID/class inside brackets

Comment: it stores the two jQuery objects inside a collection - which allows for you to call jQuery methods on them..  when you know the current element that triggers the call is `this` - you can filter it out of the collection using `HG.not(this)` - so now you can manipulate the other element that is not `this`